# htaccess url redirection with more friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP website with following URL's

www.mysite.com/11/events
www.mysite.com/12/services
www.mysite.com/13/projects

and so on. Those numbers are actually page id's to load the given page, it's an old coding.

Now I need to remove those numbers and replace all URL with only the page name. Apache version 2.2.x and PHP 5.3.x

www.mysite.com/events
www.mysite.com/projects

I would like to know what condition needs to be added in htaccess. One hint is to capture the page id for once and stop internal redirection on first instance and then add one more rewrite rule to redirect the page with page name and page id passing in background.
Help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.